# How to find a duplicate string in a string array

Tags: java

I have the following code where i want to retrieve only those values which are duplicate but could not find the right result.I don't know where i'm wrong.

```
public class TestDummy {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       String arr[] ={"lady", "bird", "is","bird","lady","cook"};
       int len = arr.length;
       System.out.println("Size "+len);
       for(int i=0 ; i<=len;i++){
           for(int j=1 ; j< len-1;j++){
            if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
              System.out.println("Duplicate "+arr[i]);
          } 
       }  
           }
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you try adding them to a set?. It is more efficient than your current approach which takes` O(n^2)`

Comment: I don't want to use set. Can you help me to know where is the error in code ?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1937083/1737819. From the map of words with their occurrences choose those that have occurencies > 1. :)

Comment: What will happen when i=1 and j=1? How can you prevent i and j from having the same value, and comparing one word to itself?

Comment: first for has an error `for(int i=0 ; i<**=**len;i++){`. Can you spot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String arr[] ={"lady", "bird", "is","bird","lady","cook"};
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(String str: arr) {
        if(map.containsKey(str)) {
            map.put(str, map.get(str)+1);
        } else{
            map.put(str, 1);
        }
    }
    for(String str: map.keySet()) {
        if(map.get(str) > 1) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate: "+ str+" count:"+map.get(str));
        }
    }
```

output:

```
Duplicate: bird count:2
Duplicate: lady count:2
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your code to :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String arr[] = { "lady", "bird", "is", "bird", "lady", "cook" };
        int len = arr.length;
        System.out.println("Size " + len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { // not <= but only <
            for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {  // start from i+1 and go upto last element
                if (arr[i].equals(arr[j])) { // use equals()
                    System.out.println("Duplicate " + arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

O/P :

```
Size 6
Duplicate lady
Duplicate bird
```

Comment: Can i get number counts as well?

Comment: @Littlebird - For that you will have to use a Map / array to keep count

Answer (score 0):

Firsty Strings are to be compared with `.equals()` not `==`

```
if(arr[i].equals(arr[j]))
{
   System.out.println("Duplicate "+arr[i]);
}
```

And I would recommend you to use `sets` as they dont allow duplicate values to be entered into it, or a list and check if it already exists using a .contains() method.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
   if(list.contains(arr[i])
     System.out.println("Duplicate" + arr[i]);
   else
     list.add(arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simpler approach like the following

```
Set<String> strings=new Hashset<String>();
for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(strings.add(arr[i])==false){
        System.out.println(arr[i]+" is a duplicate");
    }
}
```

and in your existing code do it like `arr[i].equals(arr[j])` to see if values are equal(if they are equal they are duplicate)

`==` checks for reference equivalence, while `equals()` method checks for value equivalence, so you should be using equals method whenever you need to check equivalence of two objects

hope it helps!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues.

```
   for(int i=0 ; i<len;i++){
       for(int j=i +1 ; j< len;j++){
        if(arr[i].equals(arr[j])){
          System.out.println("Duplicate "+arr[i]);
      } 
   }  
       }
```

Note that: I have change `j=1` to `j=i` and `==` to `.equals` and `<=` to `<` and `len -1` to `len`

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a list with the duplicates and their count:

```
var duplicates =
from word in arr
group word by word into g
where g.Count() > 1
select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Map of your words and occurencies.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestDummy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String arr[] = {
            "lady", "bird", "is", "bird", "lady", "cook"
        };
        Map<String, Integer> dictionary = new TreeMap<>();

        int len = arr.length;
        System.out.println("Size " + len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (dictionary.containsKey(arr[i])) {
                dictionary.put(arr[i], dictionary.get(arr[i]) + 1);
                System.out.format("Duplicate %s%n", arr[i]);
            } else {
                dictionary.put(arr[i], 1);
            }
        }
    }
}



**Output**
    Size 6
    Duplicate bird
    Duplicate lady
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] removeDuplicates(String[] array){                                           
    return new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array)).toArray(new String[0]);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

above solutions does work 
but just to make code clean you could use [Linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/)